# NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs checking what it contains

Tags: c#

This is my implementation of method I use as a parameter of:

`System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler`

->

```
void _students_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string xxx = '';

    if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems[0] != null && e.NewItems[0] is Student)
    {
        xxx = (e.NewItems[0] as Student).Name;
    }

    lstLog.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} Name:", xxx));

}
```

As you can see I use triple check to make sure that the program will not crush here.

Is there any better way of solving this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you forget to check whether there are items in the collection or not... e.NewItems.Count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if checking to see if `e.NewItems.Count > 0` is really necessary since it's usually null if there's nothing being added. And instead of `e.NewItems[0] != null && e.NewItems[0] is Student`, you can just do `e.NewItems[0] is Student` since `null is Student` is false. There's also the issue of logging something even if the name/xxx variable is empty. This might be a little abusive, but you could just do:

```
var student = (e.NewItems ?? new List<Student>()).OfType<Student>().FirstOrDefault();
if (student != null)
    lstLog.Items.Add(string.Format("Name: {0}", student.Name));
```

And if it's possible that `e.NewItems` ever contains more than one object, you might even do something like:

```
foreach (Student student in e.NewItems ?? new List<Student>())
    lstLog.Items.Add(string.Format("Name: {0}", student.Name));
```

Comment: It is first time I see `??` operator. Thank you for this example.

Answer (score 1):

I would have done something like this

```
void _students_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string name = string.Empty;

     if (e.NewItems != null && e.NewItems.Count > 0)
    {
        var student = e.NewItems[0] as Student;
        if (student != null) name = student.Name;
    }

    lstLog.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} Name:", name)); 
}
```